# While read (loop) in bash, read it by whitespace; not line-by-line

Tags: bash, while-loop

I would like to ask how to iterate the contents of the file by whitespace (\n) and not to read it line-by-line.

Here's a simple webservice code:

```
<?php

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
    print_r($data);

?>
```

When I try to run my script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
. /home/sample.txt

while read LINE; do
     curl -H "Content-Type:application/json -XPOST -k "https://sample/posthere.php" -d '{"info":"'"$info"'","grade":"'"$grade"'"}'
done < /home/sample.txt
```

Where the content of /home/sample.txt is:

```
info="student"
grade="Grade 1"

info="teacher"
grade="Grade 3"
```

Unfortunately, it results to this:

```
Array
(
    [info] => teacher
    [grade] => Grade 3
)
Array
(
    [info] => teacher
    [grade] => Grade 3
)
Array
(
    [info] => teacher
    [grade] => Grade 3
)
Array
(
    [info] => teacher
    [grade] => Grade 3
)
Array
(
    [info] => teacher
    [grade] => Grade 3
)
```

Suppose, I expect it to be like this:

```
Array
(
    [info] => student
    [grade] => Grade 1
)
Array
(
    [info] => teacher
    [grade] => Grade 3
)
```

I think I'm wrong with my **while read LINE** code in bash.
Any idea would highly be appreciated.

Comment: You are sourcing `sample.txt` in the first line. That is setting the shell variables `info` and `grade`. `while read LINE` is reading each line of the file into the `$LINE` variable (which you aren't using).

Comment: Also `\n` is newline/line-by-line and whitespace vs. newline isn't an issue here.

Comment: My bad. It should be student rather.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you source (or `.`)  `/home/sample.txt` at the top of your script, it does this:

- set `info` to `student`.
- set `grade` to `Grade 1`.
- set `info` to `teacher`.
- set `grade` to `Grade 3`.

So, when it's finished, `info` is set to `teacher` and `grade` is set to `Grade 3`.

*Then and only then,* for each line in your input file, you just use those two *fixed* values, which is why you're getting the output you see (`teacher/Grade 3` for each line).

What you want to do is to process each line as you see it, and perform the appropriate actions:

```
#!/bin/bash

doSomethingWith() {
    echo "Doing something with [$1] [$2]"
}

# Process every line.

while read LINE; do
    if [[ $LINE =~ "info=\"" ]] ; then    # Store info lines.
        info=${LINE:6}                    # Remove [line="] at start.
        info=${info%%\"}                  # Remove ["] at end.
    fi

    if [[ $LINE =~ "grade=\"" ]] ; then   # Act on grade lines.
        grade=${LINE:7}                   # Remove [grade="] at start.
        grade=${grade%%\"}                # Remove ["] at end.
        doSomethingWith "$info" "$grade"  # Process it.
    fi
done < sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' < input-file | while read ...
```

That is, simply preprocess the data and replace all sequences of spaces with a single newline.